# Executing function in a background process using a timer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Hello i am trying to implement this feature where i have a function that scans my database and returns a certain value after a set period of time maybe 5mins.  This function should run in a background process and not hinder the user in any way at all.  I have read several articles on "background workers" and "threading" but i would like some guidance on how to implement this.

eg:

```
private void func()
{
  MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

Now i want this function to execute every fifteen minutes as long as the application is running, everything should be done in a background process without interrupting the user until the message box is eventually displayed.

Comment: Use a timer. There are plenty of resources available online.

Comment: Pay attention to [different timers available in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below sample code :-

```
// Create a 1 min timer 
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);

    // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    timer.Enabled = true;


...

private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Quick question though, why am i unable to access desktop controls from withinthis event?

Comment: what type of error ur getting can you tell @BlankEDjok?

Comment: When i type the name of a control on the form it just underlines it with red.  This is unique to this event alone.

Comment: Can you check it out for me please? Hope it won't be a bother, i really need to be able to access form controls from that event.

Comment: by event you mean in OnTimedEvent method you are not able to access MessageBox right @BlankEDjok?

Comment: Yes but the messagebox was just an example, i am unable to access textboxes, labels etc. within that event.

Comment: can you remove static from method and try again @BlankEDjok?

Comment: After removing the static i am able to access the controls but i get t his error when i run my application: "Cross-thread operation not valid" or something like that.

Comment: Found the solution here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945225/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to implement your requirement. Simplest would be using a `Timer` and a `BackgroundWorker` component on your main form.

On every `Tick` of timer, you call background worker's `RunWorkerAsync` method. Do your thing in its `DoWork` event, ans display your result in `RunWorkerCompleted` so your application will not go kaboom in `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: But how do i execute the background worker's do_work event within the timer's tick event?

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread t = new Thread( new ThreadStart(func));

t.start();

private void func()
{
 while(true)
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
  Thread.Sleep(5000);
 }
}
```

Comment: Awful idea. Why tie up a thread by making it sleep for long periods?

Comment: whats the issue ? @DanielKelley

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the "not hinder the user at any way at all", but:

```
public static Thread Schedule(Action action, int delaysecs)
{
    return new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        while (true) {
            if (DateTime.Now > dateTime)
            {
                action();
                dateTime.AddSeconds(delaysecs);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000); //Adjust for accuracy
        }
    })).Start();
}
```

This code creates and returns thread that guarrantee to execute `action` every `delaysecs` seconds. Even if that `action` takes more than one second it won't delay the next `action`, and won't hinders user experience. (if it's not something heavy of course.)

Comment: This is a poor solution. Why create a thread only to make it sleep?

Comment: You create a thread and then put it to sleep - that is a waste of resources. See Neels answer - a timer is far more appropriate.

Comment: @DanielKelley The question said `not hinder the user at any way at all`, that timer will interrupt the form or whatever it's on, if it's long operation, or a message box for example.

Comment: If you believe a thread is a better option to a timer in a scenario where an operation needs to be performed on a *timed* basis then that is your prerogative. My aim is to make sure anyone reading this answer will know at least 1 person on SO disagrees with it.

Comment: @DanielKelley I can agree on the 'a waste of resources', but I don't think he is doing scientific calculation.

Comment: This is a poor solution. There's no reason to have a thread with a sleep loop when a simple timer will do. It's true that a timer *can* block the UI thread--but only if the timer executes on that thread. In the case of `System.Threading.Timer`, the callback executes on a pool thread. `System.Timers.Timer` event is raised on the UI thread only if the `SynchronizingObject` is set. The cases where a thread with a sleep loop is superior to a timer are rare. This is not one of them.

Comment: @JimMischel I think I partially agreeing with you. (I won't delete nor edit this answer, because it's unnecessary already)